# Chrome devtools, monitor when an eventhandler is attached?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to monitor some performance in a production environment. The JS is minified and uglified so I cannot easily set a breakpoint on the function that binds the event.

I have seen  in Chrome dev tools that when I inspect a particular element that I can also see the bound event handlers.

Is it possible to set a timer or create some kind of monitor that can tell me how long it has taken for the event handler to be attached to the element (on page load).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out console.time and console.timeEnd on the Console API of DevTools:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoletimelabel

I'd put the time on the very first line of code and timeEnd in the attach event funciton.

Also note that DevTools can somewhat prettify your code, when you're in sources panel, click the `{}` button on the bottom left corner of the DevTools window.

Comment: but how do I add the console.time to the first line etc?